# Getting series of "SCRIPT1002: Syntax errors" when debugging in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I just created mvc 4 application , its working fine with Firefox and Chrome. but when I try to debug this application using Internet Explorer , I'm getting series of following errors.

[image]

These are the error messages

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

once its debug , it should direct to login page

this is cshtml code of that view page

```
    @model  projet.Models.LoginViewModel

@{
    Page.Title = "Account Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Login_Layout.cshtml";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>                 </h1>
</hgroup>

<div class="form-box" id="login-box">

    <div class="header">        
        <img src="~/Images/logo.png"> <br>
         Higher Education Council
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



  <div class="body bg-gray">

       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-group"> 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName,new { id="validateHecUser_username",  @class="form-control" , placeholder="Username"  , maxlength="25"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password,new { id="validateHecUser_password",  @class="form-control" , placeholder="Password", @Value= "" , maxlength="25" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>


  </div>



    }
</div>





@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

   <script type='text/javascript'>
       $(document).ready(function () {


           $("#validateHecUser_username").bind("cut copy paste", function (e) {
               // alert('dddd');
               e.preventDefault();
           });

           $("#validateHecUser_password").bind("cut copy paste", function (e) {
               // alert('dddd');
               e.preventDefault();
           });

           $('input:submit').attr('disabled', true);
           $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
               if ($("#validateHecUser_username").val() & $("#validateHecUser_password").val() ) {
                   $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled');
               }
               else {
                   $('input:submit').attr('disabled', true);
               }
           });
       });

       $(function () {
           $(this).bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
           });
       });

   </script>


}
```

this is layout files for that view page

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
             <title>@Page.Title | my project </title>

           <link rel="icon" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/favicon.ico")"/>
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

            @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/font-awesome.min.css")
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/AdminLTE.css")

            @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js")
            @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js") 
            @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
            @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.placeholder.min.js")
            @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
            @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/ErrorPathDoesNotExist/css")


        </head>

        <body id="background">


              @RenderSection("featured", required: false)

            <div id="body">

                <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                    @RenderBody()
                </section>
            </div> 


        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)


    </body>

</html>



  @section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui") 

      <script type='text/javascript'>
          $(document).ready(function () {
              //This sets up placeholders for all input and textareas (if the browser doesn't support it)
              $('input', 'textarea').placeholder();
          });
      </script>

    }
```

Comment: You have many errors in visual studio editor for your html! You may mistyped to close a tag or something. I know IE is not smart enough to parse pages with such problems.

Comment: I checked whether I missed one of them , seems like no mismatch ,

Is there any other site available to check cshtml errors ? ( like validator.w3.org )

Comment: I don't know. Try to collapse element from inner most to outer most one by one. May be you could find the problem!

Comment: are you sure 100% this is because of losing closing tag ?